# Calling pushViewController from child controller function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, protocols

I have a root view controller that subclasses `UINavigationController`. It loads in a child view with a `UIButton`. When that button is pressed I want to make a call from the child view's corresponding view controller (lets say `ChildViewController`) to the `UINavigationController`'s `pushViewController:` method in the parent controller.

How is this possible without directly referencing the parent view controller? Is it achievable using a standard protocol method or do I have to create my own?

Comment: is the `navigationController` property an option?

Answer (score 3):

Every [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIViewController) has a property called navigationController. If a UIViewController is a part of a UINavigationController's stack, you can use the navigationController property in the following manner:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourNextViewController animated:YES];
```

There's no need to access the rootViewController only for pushing a new ViewController on the stack. This could get really awful if you had big navigation stacks.

By the way - Apple [states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) that UINavigationController is not intended for subclassing. Usually, it is a good idea to listen to their warnings and directions, so you may want to revisit the subclassing approach again.
using a subclassed UIViewController which is loaded to the UINavigationController's stack may prove a better approach.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The child `UIViewController` that contains your child `UIView` and `UIButton` should have the `parentViewController` property. You can use that to get a weak reference to your `UINavigationController` where you can message `pushViewController:animated:`

Comment: I know this post is old, but I am running into a similar problem.  Could you expand on this answer?  I can not figure out how to get the reference.  I have a button in a custom cell and want to present a UIActivityViewController.  How do you use the parentViewController property.  Thanks for your time.